# Using search-ms: or search: protocols to retrieve search results as an IShellItem

Tags: c++, windows, shell, com, windows-search

I'm trying to retrieve global file search results in Windows but the Windows Search documentation is incredibly complex and I would rather not deal with SQL for such simple functionality. Is it possible to get the search results displayed in Windows Explorer after running `search:query=%s` as an `IShellFolder` or `IShellItem` so I can process the result items in my application?

Comment: You can use the ISearchQueryHelper interface to build the SQL for you (using explorer's syntax): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb231313.aspx, but you will still have to use ADO or OLEDB to run the query. This will get back you items' paths that you can convert into IShellItem using standard shell functions

Answer (score 1):

If you want an extra window to popup, you can create an Internet Explorer window, navigate to a [search-ms url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266520.aspx), query the IShellBrowser service from IWebBrowser2's IServiceProvider implementation, then [get the active shell view and enumerate items in the view](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12029/Automate-the-Active-Windows-Explorer-or-Internet-E).

If you do not need the extra window, you can use ISearchFolderItemFactory and set a condition of PKEY_FileName with operator COP_VALUE_CONTAINS. You can also use IConditionFactory2::CreateCompoundFromArray to create a compond conditions, in SQL terms it could be something like

where fileName contains "ABC" OR fileAuthor contains "ABC" or fileFullText contains "ABC" or fileTitle contains "ABC"

You can then call ISearchFolderItemFactory::GetShellItem to get the search folder object's IShellItem interface, from which you can [call BindToHandler with BHID_EnumItems to return a shell item enumerator](https://github.com/jiangsheng/Samples/blob/master/FindDotnetInWindows/AssemblySearch/AssemblySearch.cpp).